# Only Allow Parent Factory Method to Instantiate Child Classes

Tags: java, inheritance

I have no doubt this has been asked and answered here a dozen times, but I just can't find a satisfactory answer.

I have a family of classes that I only want instantiated by the abstract parent class through a static method like this (I probably have typos here I am typing without trying to compile).

```
public abstract class Papa {
    public static Papa newInstance() {
        String strClass = Papa.figureOutTheNameOfChildClassToInstantiate();
        Papa papa = (Papa) Class.forName(strClass).newInstance();
        return papa;
    }
    public abstract void doSomething();
    ...
}
public class Child extends Papa {
    public void doSomething() { /* Do something */ }
}
```

That's more or less what I have now.  What I wish to do is be sure that the Child can only be instantiated by the factory method Papa.newInstance().  I tried to do this by making the Child's no-argument constructor private, but then Papa can't instantiate it.

So, my question is, how can I make sure Child instances are only created by the factory method Papa.newInstance()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you absolutely, positively, want to enforce this, then give `Papa` a protected constructor which takes a parameter of type `Xyzzy`. Make `Xyzzy` a protected inner class in `Papa`. Give it a private constructor. Now, only `Papa` can make instances of `Xyzzy`. Since you need an instance of `Xyzzy` to call `Papa`'s constructor, and since subclasses of `Papa` must call its constructor from their constructors, you need an instance of `Xyzzy` to call the constructor of any subclass of `Papa`. Hence, only `Papa` can call the constructors of its subclasses. Even though `Xyzzy` doesn't do anything.

Subclasses could leak their `Xyzzy` instance, which would allow other code to call subclass constructors. But you can constrain that too, by making `Xyzzy` single-use, and only so within the context of a single static factory invocation.

But to be honest, i wouldn't bother!

Comment: Using private constructors in inner classes is not a good idea - this forces the Java compiler to generate stub constructors with more visibility so that the outer class can instantiate them...

Comment: Actually I wouldn't be bothering either if it weren't for the fact that up to now I've been directly instantiating Child (and it's siblings) in my project and now I want to identify and remove all such direct instantiations and force myself to always use the factory method going forward.  But maybe even so I can still live without all the fuss...

Comment: For that sort of thing, something like Checkstyle might be the prudent option. One day, we will have a language with a type/access system powerful enough to do what you want to do, but doing this in Java seems likely to result in something a bit Lovecraftian.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of possible alternatives:

1. Use the default visibility for the child class constructors and put them in the same package as the parent class. This has the disadvantage that those classes can be instantiated by *any* other class in the same package, including any "sibling" classes.
2. Have all child classes as [nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) in the parent class. Marking them as `private static` would make them visible only to the parent class. Unfortunately, this also implies having the code of *all* classes in the same file...